# Remember login information

Tags: java, android

I would like to let the user register once and from that moment he won't need to login every time he open the app.
How would I do that?should I save the login information on the device and load it every time he tries?is it safe?maybe save only his id and then load his info from the mysql db?

**EDIT**
would you mind atleast telling me why do I get so many negative votes?so I could learn for the next time?

Comment: I didn't tried yet.. that's why I'm asking you. I'm connecting directly to the mysql server with insert/select permissions

Answer (score 2):

This is normally done with tokens. So after the first login you authenticate with your token to the web service. I personally would not recommend storing the login credentials on the local device. With rooting or simple programming errors the login date should simply be stolen.

So if the client want to login he/she can simply delete its token and on the server side the token should be deleted as well.

A common example is the usage of cookies, which are nothing else than a token. In combination with a exprire date this is secure.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on an web application.

1. After authentication generate a unique token, create a cookie add the token to cookie and save that to user's browser
2. When ever user visit to your site just check the cookie if it is alive the with the help of token get the